# How to format a read-only CD

Tags: cd, read-only

I have a CD that has Ubuntu 15.04 and I want it to have Ubuntu 14.04 because Steam is easier to setup, but if I try to format it (this is the picture of the message I'm getting):

[image: screenshot]

I have Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm having way too many issues, so I'm reinstalling if you're asking.

I googled this beforehand and someone said to input this command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/SGTL MSCN'
```

I put that command in but it gives me an arrow and I'm pretty sure it is waiting for a command (see the arrow in the terminal)

[image: screenshot]

Any commands to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a file on a CD-RW and/or CD-R. If your CD is a CD-RW you can delete the CD, e.g. with Brasero, but you can't change a single file.

One of the optical medium on which one could modify individual files, was e.g. DVD-RAM.

And the command in your second screenshots waits for a closing quote, because in your command is only the opening quote.

Comment: I would add this is a general behavior, not linked to Ubuntu but to the media itself.  In other words, you would have the same using windows.